# Deparse, substitute with three-dots arguments

Tags: r, function, arguments, metaprogramming, rlang

Let consider a typical `deparse(substitute(` R call:

```
f1 <-function(u,x,y)
{print(deparse(substitute(x)))}

varU='vu'
varX='vx'
varY='vy'
f1(u=varU,x=varX,y=varY)
```

That results in

```
[1] "varX"
```

which is what we expect and we want.

Then, comes the trouble, I try to get a similar behaviour using the `...` arguments i.e.

```
f2 <- function(...)
{  l <- list(...)
  x=l$x
  print(deparse(substitute(x))) ### this cannot work but I would like something like that
}
```

That, not surprisingly, does not work :

```
f2(u=varU,x=varX,y=varY)
[1] "\"vx\"" ### wrong ! I would like "varX"
```

I tried to get the expected behaviour using a different combination of solutions but none provides me what expected and it seems that I am still not clear enough on lazy eval to find myself the how-to in a resonable amount of time.

Comment: r u looking for `f2 <- function(...) as.character(as.list(match.call())$x)`?

Comment: @chinsoon12 Thks this is working !

Answer (score 7):

You can get the list of all unevaluated arguments by doing

```
match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)$...
```

Or, if you *only* have dot arguments, via

```
as.list(match.call()[-1L])
```

This will give you a named list, similarly to `list(...)`, but in its unevaluated form (similarly to what `substitute` does on a single argument).

An alternative is using `rlang::quos(...)` if you’re willing to use the {rlang} package, which returns a similar result in a slightly different form.