# Convert names of vector objects into the tags of the list of vectors with R

Tags: r, list, data-transform

I have some vectors, like this:

```
months <- c("january", "february", "march", "october", "december") 
weekdays <- c("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday")
seasons <- c("Summer", "Winter", "Fall", "autumn")
```

And I want to create a list like this

```
timeWords_list <- list(months,  weekdays, seasons)
```

Is there any way to tag the objects of the list directly with the names of the vector objects?

The result I want can be achieved like this:

```
names(timeWords_list) <- c("months",  "weekdays", "seasons")
```

But, Is there any way to do that directly? Without re-writing these names (in a string vector)?

Comment: `tibble::lst` does that for you if you'd like.

Answer (score 4):

Try any of these one-liners. The first one does require that each name be written twice but no character vector of names need be provided and the intent of the code is very clear.  The second one only requires that the names be written once.  The third one does not require that the names be written out at all but only works if there are no other variables whose names end in `s` -- if there were such names those variables would be included in the list as well.

No packages are used.

```
L1 <- list(months = months, weekdays = weekdays, seasons = seasons)

L2 <- mget(c("months", "weekdays", "seasons"))

L3 <- mget(ls(pattern = "s$"))
```

Comment: I had assumed the first was "known" but in hindsight should have included it anyway, just in case. I so often recommend against the `get`/`assign` functions (when abused) that I keep forgetting about them in legitimate uses like this.

Answer (score 2):

If you are already using packages from the tidyverse, then `tibble::lst` does this already:

```r
tibble::lst(months,  weekdays, seasons)
# $months
# [1] "january"  "february" "march"    "october"  "december"
# $weekdays
# [1] "Sunday"  "Monday"  "Tuesday"
# $seasons
# [1] "Summer" "Winter" "Fall"   "autumn"
```

If you aren't, though, you can bake your own, borrowing from https://stackoverflow.com/a/55019843/3358272:

```r
mylist <- function(...) setNames(list(...), as.character(match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)$...))
mylist(months,  weekdays, seasons)
# $months
# [1] "january"  "february" "march"    "october"  "december"
# $weekdays
# [1] "Sunday"  "Monday"  "Tuesday"
# $seasons
# [1] "Summer" "Winter" "Fall"   "autumn"
```

Note, though, that it doesn't always work out the way you may intend.

```r
mylist(months,  weekdays, seasons, c(1,27,pi))
# $months
# [1] "january"  "february" "march"    "october"  "december"
# $weekdays
# [1] "Sunday"  "Monday"  "Tuesday"
# $seasons
# [1] "Summer" "Winter" "Fall"   "autumn"
# $`c(1, 27, pi)`
# [1]  1.000000 27.000000  3.141593
```

`tibble::lst` does the same thing (as do many functions that try this type of trickery), so it isn't a novel problem.